# How to plot multiple plots using ComplexPortraits.jl in a for loop?

Tags: plot, julia

I am trying to use the Julia package ComplexPortraits.jl to make plots. I need to plot multiple of them at one go. The following code does not plot anything. How do I make it work?

```
using ComplexPortraits
@ComplexPortraits.import_normal

for i in 1:5
    ComplexPortraits.phaseplot(2 - 2*im, -2 + 2im, z -> z) 
end
```